# Error (qt5-qtwebkit) trying to install notepadqq on Redhat 7.4

Tags: rhel, software-installation, yum, dependencies

I am trying to install notepadqq on Redhat 7.4. To do this I run

```
sudo yum install notepadqq
```

However, I get the following errors,

```
Error: Package: notepadqq-0.46.1-0.el7.centos.x86_64 (FedoraPeople-sea)
           Requires: libQt5WebKit.so.5()(64bit)
Error: Package: notepadqq-0.46.1-0.el7.centos.x86_64 (FedoraPeople-sea)
           Requires: libQt5WebKitWidgets.so.5()(64bit)
Error: Package: notepadqq-0.46.1-0.el7.centos.x86_64 (FedoraPeople-sea)
           Requires: qt5-qtwebkit
```

If I try to install the required dependencies, I am told:

```
 No package qt5-qtwebkit available.
```

How I I update my qt5 so I can install notepadqq?

Comment: I'm confused as to why CentOS packages from a FedoraPeople-sea repository are showing up on your RHEL system.

Comment: @JeffSchaller, I may have done that. I did the wget command `sudo wget -O /etc/yum.repos.d/sea-devel.repo http://sea.fedorapeople.org/sea-devel.repo`. The thought process was that a Fedora repository would work on Redhat. I was under the impression that a Fedora program would work on Redhat.